# Add "%" to a constantly changing string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, label, nsslider

I have a `NSSlider` and an `NSLabel`. When the slider's value changes it changes the label's text to the new value. My problem is that I want to a "%" at the end, but whenever I try to change my code, error occurs.

Here's my code:

```
int sliderValue = [_opacSlider intValue];
NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sliderValue];
[_opacLabel setStringValue:stringValue];
```

What I attempted doing was this:

```
[_opacLabel setStringValue:(stringValue, @"%")];
```

But then the label doesn't change and remains "%".

Any ideas why this is not working and what I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `stringWithFormat:` method interprets `%` as a special character, you need to use `%%` to print a single `%`:

```
int sliderValue = [_opacSlider intValue];
NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%%",sliderValue];
//                                                     ^^
[_opacLabel setStringValue:stringValue];
```